# Pydantic using a list from .env file with BaseSettings

Tags: python, pydantic, python-dotenv, pydantic-settings

After updating pydantic from 1.9 to 2.6, my lists in my .env file no longer work.  I am wondering if there is a new syntax or other setting I need to enable to get the same behavior.

This is what I had before

```
`my_list: list[str]`
```

With the the .env file as
`MY_LIST=["a","b"]`

Which would work as expected in version 1.9, now I get the error

```
  Input should be a valid list [type=list_type, input_value='["a","b"]', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/list_type
```

I haven't been able to find any permutation for it not to interpret the input as a str.  Other non-list variables work fine

In summary, the following code works in 1.9

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings, Field
import os
import logging
import sys

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    my_list: list[str] = Field(..., env="MY_LIST")

    class Config:
        env_file = f'{os.environ.get("ENV")}.env'
        env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'
        env_prefix = f'{os.environ.get("ENV")}_'
        extra='ignore'

try:
    settings = Settings()
    print(settings)
except Exception as e:
    logging.critical(f"required settings not provided, shutting down - {e}")
    sys.exit(1)
```

`result - my_list=['a', 'b']`

Update to 2.6 and use pydantic_settings and this gets an error

```
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings
import os
import logging
import sys

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    my_list: list[str] = Field(..., env="MY_LIST")

    class Config:
        env_file = f'{os.environ.get("ENV")}.env'
        env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'
        env_prefix = f'{os.environ.get("ENV")}_'
        extra='ignore'

try:
    settings = Settings()
    print(settings)
except Exception as e:
    logging.critical(f"required settings not provided, shutting down - {e}")
    sys.exit(1)
```

```
CRITICAL:root:required settings not provided, shutting down - 1 validation error for Settings
my_list
  Input should be a valid list [type=list_type, input_value='["a","b"]', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/list_type
```

Is there any way to get the original behavior back?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing `env="MY_LIST"` to `alias="MY_LIST"`. Oddly, the env_prefix (for other variables) was interfering with it.